# Is there a way to access a web page that is not supported in WPF WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, webbrowser-control

I'm new to WPF and I was trying to build an application that could support three separate webBrowser controls of Microsoft Teams. The problem is that when Microsoft Teams loads it tells me that my browser isn't supported. Do you know of any possible solutions to this?

I've tried using WindowsFormsHost and hosting a WebBrowser from there to see if it may work but it got the same result.

Comment: I managed to do it using the DotNetBrowser API, so now I have three instances of the Microsoft Teams app. However, I don''t think they are independent, that is, when I log into one all the others are automatically logged in and I need a solution for that now.

Comment: Yeah, all of the browsers are going to share the same cache. So they will all have access to the same cookies, sessions, etc,

Comment: I managed to do it using CefSharp like the answer said as I needed to pay for DotNetBrowser and didnt know, I needed seperate contexts for each browser, that is, they all have different cookies which was quite easy using cefSharp when compared to DotNetBrowser. The only complaint I have with CefSharp is its performance with WPF is quite laggy since it doesn't render directly to the app but to a bitmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CefSharp` library.

See [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/881315/Display-HTML-in-WPF-and-CefSharp-Tutorial-Part).

Sample:

```
<Window x:Class="Sample1.MainWindow"

        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

        xmlns:cefSharp="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"

        Title="MainWindow" Height="550" Width="625">
    <Grid>
        <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Grid.Row="0"

        Address="https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: CefSharp Guide]